# data fair installation : docker nginx container keeps restarting

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to install Data-Fair locally using Docker, following the instructions provided on their website: https://data-fair.github.io/3/install/install.

When I run the command docker-compose --env-file data-fair.env up -d, the nginx container keeps restarting. Upon checking the logs, I encountered the following error:

```
"proxy_busy_buffers_size" must be less than the size of all "proxy_buffers" minus one buffer in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32
```

I have inspected the container's nginx.conf file but couldn't find any proxy-related parameters. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.

Could someone please help me understand how to fix the problem with the nginx container continuously restarting and address the "proxy_busy_buffers_size" error?

[image]
Thank you in advance!